# The 'Visual Studio Explorers and Designer Package' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

Every time I open solution in Visual Studio 2015 I get following message:

[image]

Here are last entries from ActivityLog.xml:

```
<entry>
   <record>827</record>
   <time>2015/12/23 11:26:13.919</time>
   <type>Error</type>
   <source>VisualStudio</source>
   <description>SetSite failed for package [Visual Studio Explorers and Designers Package][Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]:{   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.VSDMenus.Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.VSDesignerPackage.VSDesignerPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)}</description>
   <guid>{8D8529D3-625D-4496-8354-3DAD630ECC1B}</guid>
   <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
   <errorinfo>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</errorinfo></entry>
```

I followed suggestions found in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521438/vs2015-the-nugetpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly) but with no success.

Unfortunately re-installing NuGet via Extensions and Updates doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I suspect a repair of Visual Studio 2015 and re-application of update 1 is required...

Comment: Could you resolve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If @batressc solution doesn't work, you have to delete the `.VS` folder in the solution folder also.

So:

1. Close all VS Windows
2. Delete folder `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`
3. Delete Folder `[Solution Folder]\.vs`

Comment: Confirmed, deleting BOTH the ComponentModelCache folder and the .vs folder worked. Deleting only the ComponentModelCache folder by itself didn't work.

Comment: Deleting the `.vs` folder was enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: Just deleting cache folder worked for me - but... not immediately.  Had to deal with error 1 more time and then load any other project.  Close VS and re-open VS and the error was gone.

Answer (score 12):

Delete the file `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.Cache`in the folder `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

Comment: Actually, resetting the Visual Studio settings worked for me, but both ideas seem like good troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 1):

This one helps with VS 2017:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160124/failed-to-load-package-monoandroiddesignerpackage.html

1) Start VS

2) File->New->Project->Xamarin app (either iOS or Android)

3) Now click the Toolbox

4) Close VS

Comment: I concur with you for VS 2017

Answer (score 1):

Deleting this folder did the trick for me.

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_14b774ca

Comment: You da man! Worked immediately. I deleted all folders in that directory (multiple vs versions).

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me was removing "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2"

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command prompt help me solve the problem on VS 2017 Community. I never tried on other VS version though. Let me know if it works in other version:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /resetskippkgs
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on .netcore 3.1 only:

The 'windows forms remote designer hosting package' package did not load correctly

Resolved with the help of all of the answers here.

Remove the entire contents of the directories:

1. The .vs - in the project
2. c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_1cac4d16\