# Why do I get the message "The 'NuGetPackage' package did not load correctly"?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I spent the weekend Updating my Visual Studio 2015 installation to Update 3.
And I installed the Core .Net CLI (Command Tools Interface).
And rant the update "ASP.Net and WebTools tooling".

I get back to work, start Visual Studio, open our project, and now I get this:

---

The 'NuGetPackage' package did not load correctly.

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file:

'C:\Users\samuel\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'

Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.

Continue to show this error message?

---

Here is the error from the Activity Log:

```
CreateInstance failed for package [NuGetPackage]Source:
  &apos;mscorlib&apos;
  Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;NuGet.Tools,        Version=3.4.4.1321, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;
  or one of its dependencies.
  The system cannot find the file specified.
  &#x000D;
  &#x000A;System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
  Could not load file or assembly &apos;NuGet.Tools, Version=3.4.4.1321,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;
  or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file     specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;NuGet.Tools, Version=3.4.4.1321,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String     codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,     StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,     Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean     suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String     codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,     StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,     Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean     suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName        (AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly     reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean     throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    &#x000D;&#x000A;
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String     typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[]     args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence     securityInfo, StackCrawlMark&amp;
  stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String     assemblyName, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)    &#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;
  WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;
  To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value         [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;
  Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind     failure logging.&#x000D;
  &#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value     [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
  <guid>{5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC}</guid>
```

---

Uninstalling and reinstalling Nuget Package Manager from Tools -> Extensions an Updates seems to have fixed it.

We'll see. Someone on another post said they thought it worked but then came back and said it didn't:
[VS2015 - The 'NuGetPackage' package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521438/vs2015-the-nugetpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly)

Comment: Check out the solution in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521438/vs2015-the-nugetpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly). P.s. It worked for me, too.

Comment: Should set that as the answer @eg16

Comment: @Hutjepower I added my comment as an answer so it is helpful for the others.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this answer: [VS2015 - The 'NuGetPackage' package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521438/vs2015-the-nugetpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly)

> Completely removing NuGet via Extensions and Updates, restarting VS
>   then re-installing NuGet via Extensions and Updates solved the issue
>   for me. A full VS reinstall was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on update or re-install the nuGet via Extensions and Updates.

```
Tools > Extensions and Updates Updates > Visual Studio Gallery > Nuget Package
```