# VS 2013 NuGet Package did not load correctly (Windows 10 OS)

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, windows-10, nuget-package

I don't know if my problem is OS related.

I installed and created a few projects in VS 2013 in Windows 7 and everything is working fine.

But my workplace wants us to upgrade to Windows 10. So I installed VS 2013 (the same way I installed it to my Windows 7 OS) then I tried to open some of my works and got the following error:

> The 'NuGETPackage' package did not load correctly.

In ActivityLog.xml it was something like this:

> Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Tools,  or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I also checked Extensions and Updates, NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2013 is in the list.

I tried to repair (in Control Panel > Programs) but still the error shows.

Answer (score 1):

> VS 2013 NuGet Package did not load correctly (Windows 10 OS)

One possibility is that Nuget package manager was destroyed after upgrade the system to windows 10. So please try:

1. Remove NuGet via Extensions and Updates.
2. Remove the existing NuGet.Config file held in `c:\users\name\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`
3. Restarting VS then re-installing NuGet via Extensions and Updates

Besides, try to close all Visual Studio instances, then delete all files in the following folder:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Also you can check the more answer here: [The 'NuGetPackage' package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521438/vs2015-the-nugetpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly).